# How to prevent a long table with \hline from starting on a newpage when content size grows?

Tags: tables, longtable, report

**TL;DR - I want to know how I can prevent the `longtable` with `hline` going to the next page entirely when there isn't enough content space.**

I've decided to write my dissertation at college using latex. Tables have been particularly strenuous as I can't seem to find any resources to will help me figure out how I can make the content of a `longtable` with `hlines` continue to the next page instead of starting on a new page. To give more info, the screenshots below show what I **WANT** vs what I **HAVE**

| What I want | What I have |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Content in the 4th column continouing] | [image] |

#### Commands for replication

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{SO}
\author{Visal Rajapakse}
\date{September 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{longtable}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} 
\hline
foo & bar \\ \hline 
% As rendered in the document, the first row of the long table remains in page 1, while the rest of the content moves to the next page as there isn't enough vertical space in page 1 to show the content in the second row. What I want is to have most of the content in the second row to remain in page 1, while the extra content of row 2 that wouldn't fit in page 1 to start in page 2. Such that, there isn't a huge space in page 1
Something 1 & \lipsum[1] \\ \hline 
foo & bar \\ \hline

\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The output of the above can be seen

[image]

The overleaf dummy document I made for this question can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/6759497747cntjbzpvbrmx)

I have also tried the solution [here](https://newbedev.com/how-to-disable-pagebreak-on-hline-in-longtable) but it doesn't seem to work. Instead, it brings the table headers down to the next page, and the overflowing content goes beyond the footer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: firstly remove the `center` environement. `longtable` should never be in `center`.  please fix the example so that we can run it and see the problem, the page breaking depends on code you have not shown.

Comment: understood, let me re-run and edit the code if it needs updating

Comment: I ran the code in an empty document just now. It's the same result.

Comment: Break of long table can happen only between rows and not inside rows. Probably the texts in cells of the second row is so big, that they cannot be fit in available space after first row, so consequently this  row is pushed to the next page.

Comment: as documented in the longtable package manual you can put the hline and as many rows as needed  into the `\endlastfoot` rather than have it in the table body then it will stay unbroken

Comment: I just tried this out, it seems to work with the long table without `hline`. similar to what @Zarko mentioned

Comment: please edit your question to include an example of the problem. If I fix the example to be a document  with  `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}\begin{document}`  at the start and `\end{document}` at the end there is no bad page break.

Comment: I made a new document on overleaf and did as you have mentioned. It's the same result. I have edited my answer to include all the code for this new sample project. Thank you

Comment: If you require the link to the sample overleaf document I created, you can find it [here](https://www.overleaf.com/6759497747cntjbzpvbrmx)